# Right Triangle Angle problem

Tags: triangles, problem-solving, angle

I know that this can be easy, but I found it a bit difficult so maybe someone can just explain or give a hint to me.

I have a right triangle $ABC$ with points $D$ and $E$ on its hypotenuse so $AB=AE$ and $BC=CD$. I need to find angle $DBE$.

So here's two isosceles triangles (or isn't it?) $BDC$ and $ABE$. I think I need these to solve that angle. But what to do next?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Let $\angle A = \alpha$ so that $\angle C=90°-\alpha$.

From the isosceles triangles you have:
$$
\angle (ABE)=\frac{180°-\alpha}{2} \qquad \angle(DBC)=\frac{90°+\alpha}{2}
$$
now use:
$$
90°=\angle(ABC)=\angle (ABE)+\angle(DBC)- \angle(DBE)
$$

Comment: $\angle BDC=90^o-\alpha$ not $\angle DBC$ surely? [It is $2\alpha$]

Comment: @almagest. Thank you !  I edit.